# Oracle Discoverer Reporting for inbetween dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle Discoverer 11g

I'm trying to create a report that would generate certain dates. For example

The column would be called Date and the only results I would like to come back are from the current date minus 20 months (assuming 600days). So 20 months back until the current date. Is this possible?\

So far, I am here and can't figure out how to write the 20 months back:

```
units.Date(SYSDATE, 'DD-Mon-YY - ???)
```

I was placing this under Tools > Edit Calculations

Let me know if you guys need any more information.

Update: I went ahead and tried this, but recieved this error. Not sure what i means.

[image]

Comment: I guess an easier way to query it in Discoverer would be to write it as within those 20 months (600ish days)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like from your post that you want the time between today and the unit.date time. Meaning, that if your unit.date was 1/1/2015 and today is 4/14/2015, then your calculation would return "103" days. Assuming my interpretation is correct, then you should just enter the following as your calc:

**TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(units.date)**

The EUL_DATE_TRUNC will format the date to a specified format, which I don't think is needed for your calculation.